# How can I make my pattern matching function stop reporting non-matches?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a pattern matching function. 
I want to check if a string ends with any 'slice' of a particular substring, then return a dictionary containing a Boolean and the matching string (if any).

So if str1 is:

```
ABCD
```

And str2 is:

```
HDNABCD
```

Or str2 is:

```
HDNSHAB
```

The function should return:

```
results = {'match': True, 'string': '<matching string>'}
```

(*even a string ending in a single A character should return True*)

Whereas a non-match should return:

```
results = {'match': False, 'string': ''}
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
def matchpatend(str1, str2):
    '''Find any substring at the end of a string'''
    index = len(str1)
    while index > 0:
        index = index - 1
        if str2.endswith(str1):
            result = {'match': True,
                      'string': str(str1)}
            return result
        elif str2.endswith(str1[:index]):
            result = {'match': True,
                      'string': str(str1[:index])}
            return result
```

And here it is when used in the body of the program.

```
adpater_seq_1 = 'GACTGCAT'
with open(fastq, 'r') as in_f_obj, open(new_file_1, 'w') as out_f_obj: 
    line_count = 0
    id_seq = ''
    base_seq = ''
    for line in in_f_obj:  # Read the fastq file line by line
        line_count += 1
        if line_count % 4 == 1:  # Find the read ID line.
            id_seq = line.rstrip()  # Store the read ID line.
        elif line_count % 4 == 2:  # Find the sequence line.
            base_seq = line.rstrip()  # Store the sequence line.

            results = matchpatend(adapter_seq_1, base_seq)
            if results['match'] is True:
                out_f_obj.write("{}\n{}\nAdapter contamination: {}\n".format(id_seq, base_seq, results['string']))
            elif results['match'] is False:
                break
```

The code correctly outputs matches and their matching strings, but it also outputs non-matches with blank strings to the output file.

How can I stop the program from writing out False matches? Is there a better way of writing this function?

Comment: Why should it be true for `HDNSHAB`?

Comment: Because it ends with `AB`, so it should match as ending in `ABCD[:2]`.

Comment: To clarify, do you want *any* substring to match (e.g. `"BC"`, `"CD"` etc.), or only `str1[:i]` for some `i` (i.e. only `"A"`, `"AB"`, `"ABC"`, or `"ABCD"`), which is what your existing code implies?

Comment: The match needs to be for `str1[:i]` for some `i`, so, `ABCD`, `ABC`, `AB` or `A`

Comment: @umbro_tracksuit Ok. By the way, `if results["match"] is True` is redundant here, you can just use `if results["match"]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which first generates all leading substrings of the pattern, in descending order of length (since I guess you want to match as long a substring as you can?), and then iterates through them, checking each one in turn.

```
def leading_substrings(string):
    return (string[:i] for i in range(len(string), 0, -1))

def match_pattern_end(pattern, sequence):
    for sub in leading_substrings(pattern):
        if sequence.endswith(sub):
            return {"match": True, "string": sub}
    return {"match": False, "string": ""}

print(match_pattern_end("ABCD", "HDNABCD"))  # {'match': True, 'string': 'ABCD'}
print(match_pattern_end("ABCD", "HDNHABC"))  # {'match': True, 'string': 'ABC'}
print(match_pattern_end("ABCD", "HDNSHCD"))  # {'match': False, 'string': ''}
print(match_pattern_end("ABCD", "HDNSHAB"))  # {'match': True, 'string': 'AB'}
print(match_pattern_end("ABCD", "HDNSAGH"))  # {'match': False, 'string': ''}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! The code needs to match `str1[:i]` for some `i`, so, `ABCD`, `ABC`, `AB` or `A`. After a bit of fiddling around, my code correctly matches, but for some reason its printing out False matches as well as True matches.